# An inequality with S.O.S method

Tags: inequality

Hi i have an inequality here :)
Let $a,b,c\geq{0}$ prove that
$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{2a^2-ab+2b^2}\geq{\frac{a+b+c}{3}}$

I tried using S.O.S (sum of square)
.I turned the inequality into

$S=\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2\frac{2b-a}{2b^2-ba+2a^2}\geq{0}$

Let $Sc=\frac{2b-a}{2b^2-ab+2a^2}$
Sa and Sb define similarly
Note that if $a\geq{b}\geq{c}$ and

1.$Sb,Sb+Sa,Sb+Sc\geq{0}\ then \S\geq{0}$

2.$Sa,Sc,Sa+2Sb,Sc+2Sb\geq{0}\ then\ S\geq{0}$

3.$Sb,Sc,a^2Sb+b^2Sa\geq{0}\ then 
 S\geq{0}$

and i still haven't done the math.everyone can share your opinion and thanks for the help

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h66271p392422

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

My old solution(18 years ago).

We need to prove $$\sum\frac{a^3}{2a^2-ab+2b^2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{3}$$ or $$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^3}{2a^2-ab+2b^2}-\frac{a}{3}-\frac{a-b}{3}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2(2b-a)}{2a^2-ab+2b^2}\geq0.$$
Now, if $\{\frac{a}{b},\frac{b}{c},\frac{c}{a}\}\subset(0,2]$, so our inequality is true.

Let $a=\max\{a,b,c\}.$

1)$a\geq b\geq c.$

Thus, $\frac{c}{a}\in(0,1].$

1.1 $a\geq2b.$

We have $$\frac{a^3}{2a^2-ab+2b^2}\geq\frac{a}{2}$$ and $$\frac{b^3}{2b^2-bc+2c^2}\geq\frac{b}{3}.$$

Hence, $$\sum\frac{a^3}{2a^2-ab+2b^2}\geq\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{3}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{3}.$$
1.2 $b\geq2c.$

Thus, $$\sum\frac{a^3}{2a^2-ab+2b^2}\geq\frac{a}{3}+\frac{b}{2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{3}.$$
2) $a\geq c\geq b.$

Thus, $\frac{c}{a}\in(0,2], \frac{b}{c}\in(0,2].$

Let $a\geq2b.$

Hence, $$\frac{a^3}{2a^2-ab+2b^2}\geq\frac{a}{2}$$ and $$\frac{b^3}{2b^2-bc+2c^2}\geq\frac{b}{3}-\frac{c}{9}.$$

and from here $$2t^3-7t^2+5t+3\geq0,$$ where $t=\frac{c}{b}\geq1,$
which is true.

Hence, $$\sum\frac{a^3}{2a^2-ab+2b^2}\geq\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{3}-\frac{c}{9}+\frac{c^3}{2c^2-ac+2a^2}.$$
But $$\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{3}-\frac{c}{9}+\frac{c^3}{2c^2-ca+2a^2}\geq\frac{a+b+c}{3}$$ it's
$$6x^3-19x^2+14x+2\geq0,$$ where $x=\frac{a}{c}\geq1$ and we are done!

Comment: Thanks you so much arqady.18 years ago really?it's even older than me, a 15 year old boy

Comment: @Question You are welcome. I have also a solution by C-S, but it's not so nice.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Nice 18 years ago.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg awesome. i think i have a pure S.O.S solution here, i'll post it when i have time to edit